# Converting binary to decimal using recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, binary, converters

I have this much done, but I can't figure out what to put into my argument for my recursive method. I don't know what to put into  **num1 = (Math.pow(base,(binToDecimal(*s.length()-1*))));**. s.length()-1 doesn't work because it's not a string but I don't know what to put in here. Also is my recursive method going towards my base case? My idea is that every time, it reduces the string's length by one each time and will stop when the string's length is zero but I don't think it's working. Can you also use Math.pow to do this? I've seen some other solutions online and none of them use Math.pow

```
public static int binToDecimal(String s)
{
    //base case
    if(s.equals("1"))
        return 1;
    if(s.equals("0"))
        return 0;

    int num1 = 0;
    int finalAnswer = 0;
    int base = 2.0;
    //recursive case        
    if(s.length() > 1)
        num1 = (Math.pow(base,(binToDecimal(s.length()-1))));
        finalAnswer = num1 + finalAnswer;
    return
        finalAnswer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version of a recursive algorithm. Each iteration takes the last binary digit, calculates the binary value of the rest of the string multiplied by 2 (shifting to the left), and adds the value of the last digit to it.

```java
public int binChar(char c) {
    return c == '1' ? 1 : 0;
}

public int binToDecimal(String s) {
    switch(s.length()) {
        case 0: return 0;
        case 1: return binChar(s.charAt(0));
        default: {
            int last = s.length() - 1;
            char c = s.charAt(last);
            s = s.substring(0,last);
            return binToDecimal(s) * 2 + binChar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not too confident with switches because I have never really used them that much. I'm still trying to figure out what I can put instead of s.length()-1 into (binToDecimal(s.length()-1))

Comment: Use `s.substring(0, s.length()-1)` instead. It's probably what you were trying to do anyway.

Comment: thanks I got that part working, now to fix it so it gives me the correct answer